# String to date in php

Tags: php, datetime

I spent on this couple days and tried to google it as well without luck.
I have a date stored in string $dob = '2012-10-06 10: 45: 45 +0000';
I am trying to convert it to date using the following code:

```
$timezone = 'Europe/Brussels';  
$d = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d H:i:s P",$dob ,new DateTimeZone($timezone)); 
    echo $d->format("Y-m-d");
```

But I am getting the following error message:
Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object
How can I create a DateTime from string in the following format: 2012-10-06 10: 45: 45 +0000 ?
Thank you for help...

Comment: Your call to `createFromFormat` is returning `FALSE`, hence `$d` being a non-object when you call `format` on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like there are spaces in your date that aren't in your pattern.  Also, P => O because P has a colon where O is just 4 digits.

Try `"Y-m-d H: i: s O"` instead.

You're probably getting the error because createFromFormat() fails and you don't actually have a DateTime object in $d.

If that doesn't fix it, look into [DateTime::getLastErrors()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.getlasterrors.php).  That can help explain the problem.

Here's a link to a PHP sandbox with my suggestion working:  http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ee06a025fb9ab47f136eba221382c8b2f84be703

You have to click the run button below the code.

Comment: It's exactly like P, except P expects a : in the middle.  O would be +0000, P would look like +00:00.

Answer (score -1):

```
YY-MM-DD HH: II: SS tzcorrection
```